# Node.js или PHP?

Tags: javascript

Хотелось бы узнать мнение экспертов,
какой язык бэкенда стоит изучать?
Node.js или PHP?

Comment: python django..

Comment: Хотите сказать, что Python django лучше PHP и Node.js?

Comment: Как по мне, то python django удобнее PHP и Node.js

Comment: Смотря для каких целей

Comment: @Cyrax django низкоуровневый и высокоуровневый одновременно. Конечно с хостингом нужно запарится, но написание довольно быстрое и расширеное.

Comment: нода заменяет пхп потихоньку, питон жыв благодаря павелу дураву, если бы не павел, то питон был бы там где ему самое место (в канаве)

Comment: Учить нужно Rust, конечно же :)

Comment: @Vadim Стало очень любопытно, причем тут вообще Дуров?

Comment: @tutankhamun телега

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ зависит от того что вы хотите. Слушать чьи-то предпочтения считаю неверным, работать вам и доверять свой выбор какому-то комментарию или ответу неверным. Если вы хотите посветить себя интернету то оба варианта имеют как большие плюсы и минусы тоже. Начните с html css javascript без каких либо фреймворков или технологий. Конечно это противно долго и большой проект писать очень не удобно, но потом попробовав php или node.js вы будите в восторге от обоих.